# MySQL add column with default value of current_user() returns syntax error

Tags: mysql

Having an issue with default column values...

The following works:

```
alter table chartdata.reddit_comments add modified_datetime timestamp default now() on update now();
```

(adds a `modified_date` column which defaults to the current timestamp.)

However, the following returns a syntax error:

```
alter table chartdata.reddit_comments add modified_by varchar(50) default current_user() on update current_user();
```

`[2018-04-06 16:56:21] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_user() on update current_user()' at line 1`

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: is just invalid MySQL code you need to use triggers... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83899/mysql-created-by-or-updated-last-by

Comment: See [13.1.18 CREATE TABLE Syntax :: DEFAULT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html): `Specifies a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column.`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't have enough rep to comment on your duplicate issue but check out the tsibble package

```
library(data.table)
foo <- data.table(accountid = c(rep(1, 366), rep(2, 366), rep(3, 366)), 
                  orderday = as.POSIXct(rep(seq(as.Date("2018/1/1"), as.Date("2019/1/1"), "days"), 3)),
                  ordervolume = rep(rnorm(366), 3))

library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)

df <- foo %>% as_tsibble(key = id(accountid),index =orderday)

df

#Pick a size
n = 3

# Using tsibble

df %>% 
  group_by(accountid) %>% 
  mutate(rolling = slide_dbl(ordervolume, ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE), .size = 3))
```